# What is the "T:" for when used in a cref

Tags: c#, xml-comments

What does the `T:` part mean in the use of the cref attribute here?

```
<see cref="T:System.Windows.Form.Control"/>
```

and

```
<see cref="System.Windows.Form.Control"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

It's essentially an annotation to what the code reference is referring to when the compiler generates ids in the documentation. Here, the `T` indicates that the name `System.Windows.Form.Control` that's being referenced is a *type* and not a namespace or other member.

On its own, the text `System.Windows.Form.Control` could have different meanings.  It could be a namespace for instance, or the `Control` member of a `System.Windows.Form` object.  This helps describe what exactly it is.

You can see more information on the other conventions the compiler uses in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx).

The other prefixes are as follows:

```
N   namespace
T   type: class, interface, struct, enum, delegate
F   field
P   property (including indexers or other indexed properties)
M   method (including such special methods as constructors, operators, and so forth)
E   event
!   error string
```